# How do I open my edit complaint page for one specific complaint in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have a view complaints page where a user can view the complaints he/she have submitted. When the user clicks on one of the cards, I need a new page to open where the user can view the details of that complaint and edit it as well.

It should go from here:
[image]

to here: Where they can view details and make changes as well:

[image]

This is my models.py:

```
class Complaint(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE, null = True, blank=True)
   id = models.AutoField(blank=False, primary_key=True)
   reportnumber = models.CharField(max_length=500 ,null = True, blank= False)
   eventdate = models.DateField(null=True, blank=False)
   event_type = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
   device_problem = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
   manufacturer = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
   product_code = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
   brand_name = models.CharField(max_length = 300, null=True, blank=True)
   exemption = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
   patient_problem = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
   event_text = models.TextField(null=True, blank= True)
   document = models.FileField(upload_to='static/documents', blank=True, null=True)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.reportnumber
```

views.py:

```
def EditComplaints(request):
   complaint = request.user.complaint
   form = ComplaintForm(instance=complaint)
   if request.method == 'POST':
       form = ComplaintForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=complaint)
       if form.is_valid():
           form.save()
   context = {'form': form}
   return render(request, 'newcomplaint.html', context)
```

template (the view history page):

```
<div class="col right-pro-con">
        <div class="img-cir">
            <form method='POST' action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %} {% if request.user.profile.profile_pic.url %}
                <img src={{request.user.profile.profile_pic.url}} alt="" width="100px" height="100px" class="pro-img"> {% else %}
                <img src="{% static 'profileimages/msi.jpg' %}" alt="" width="100px" height="100px" class="pro-img"> {% endif %}
                <p class="my-name">{{request.user.profile.first}}
                    <p>
                        <p class="my-email-id">{{request.user.profile.email}}</p>
            </form>
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="con-us">CONTACT US</a>
    </div>
```

template(edit complaint page):

```
<div class="col-lg middle middle-complaint-con">
        <i class="fas fa-folder-open fa-4x comp-folder-icon"></i>
        <h1 class="all-comp">New Complaint</h1>

        <form class="" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <p class="sub-typ-wr">Submit Type</p>
            <a href="/Login/Add-Complaint/Document-Style/"><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary document-btn">Document</button></a>

            <div class="rep-num">
                <label class="written-label" for="">Report Number</label>
                <div class="written-txt-field">{{form.reportnumber}}</div>
            </div>

            <div class="eve-dte">
                <label class="written-label" for="">Event Date</label>
                <div class="written-txt-field">{{form.eventdate}}</div>
            </div>

            <div class="eve-typ">
                <label class="written-label" for="">Event Type</label>
                <div class="written-txt-field">{{form.event_type}}</div>
            </div>

            <div class="dev-pro">
                <label class="written-label" for="">Device Problem</label>
                <div class="written-txt-field">{{form.device_problem}}</div>
            </div>

            <label class="written-label eve-txt" for="">Event Text</label>

            <div class="Manufacturer">
                <label class="written-label" for="">Manufacturer</label>
                <div class="written-txt-field">{{form.manufacturer}}</div>
            </div>

            <div class="pro-code">
                <label class="written-label" for="">Product Code</label>
                <div class="written-txt-field">{{form.product_code}}</div>
            </div>

            <div class="brand-name">
                <label class="written-label" for="">Brand Name</label>
                <div class="written-txt-field">{{form.brand_name}}</div>
            </div>

            <div class="exem">
                <label class="written-label" for="">Exemption</label>
                <div class="written-txt-field">{{form.exemption}}</div>
            </div>

            <div class="pat-pro">
                <label class="written-label" for="">Patient Problem</label>
                <div class="written-txt-field">{{form.patient_problem}}</div>
            </div>



            <div class="comp-textarea">{{form.event_text}}</div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary attach-btn-1"><div class="fas fa-file-upload">{{form.document}}</div></button>
            <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-secondary save-btn-1"><i class="fas fa-save"></i> Save</button>
        </form>

    </div>
```

url:

```
urlpatterns = [
   path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
   path('Home/', landing_page.views1.landing, name= 'Home'),
   path('Registration/', accounts.views.RegisterPage),
   path('Login/', accounts.views.LoginPage, name='Login'),
   path('Login/Profile/', accounts.views.profile, name='Profile'),
   path('Logout/', accounts.views.LogoutUser, name='Logout'),
   path('Login/Add-Complaint/', accounts.views.NewComplaint, name = 'New'),
   path('Login/Add-Complaint/Document-Style/', accounts.views.DocComplaint, name='doc'),
   path('My-History/', accounts.views.History, name='MyHistory'),
   path('Complaint/', accounts.views.EditComplaints, name='Complaint')
 ]
```

How do I do this? What should I add in the code for the code to open that particular complaints details and for that complaints page to edit?

Comment: are you asking where should I add a link in the list page for the users to go to the edit page?

Comment: No no... like I don't know how to or what type of url to use when the user wants to open the edit page for a specific complaint. I don't know how to navigate from the view page to that edit page for that specific complaint. What all changes do I need to make in my code for that. I have a list of complaints and if the user clicks on one then the edit page for that one should open up. So how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

okay, so you already have a view. What you need is some sort of unique identifier to help you figure out the actual object that the user wants to edit.

So, in your `urls.py` you will have to add a pattern similar to:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('complain/<int:pk>/edit/', views.EditComplaint.as_view(), name='edit-complain'),
    ...
]
```

Inside your `views.py`, handle it in a manner something similar to:

```py
from django.views.generics import UpdateView
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import UserPassesTestMixin
from django.http import Http404
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

from .models import Complaint

class EditComplaint(UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Complaint
    fields = ('info', )  # define whatever field that you want to render

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # do your form validation here

    def test_func(self):
        """ensuring the reporter themselves is updating the complain"""
        complain = self.get_object()

        if self.request.user == complain.user:
            return True
        raise Http404(_('This complain does not exist'))
  
    def success_url(self):
        # this is only required if your model doesn't have a `get_absolute_url` method
        # return the actual url of the instance
```

All you need now is to add a link inside your template for the `EditComplaint` view(assuming you already have the list of donations inside your list template as donations).

Something along the lines should do the job

```
{% for complaint in complaints %}
    <a href="{% url 'edit-complaint' complaint.pk %}">Edit Complaint</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this using functions and not classes? I'm getting an error in my url paths while using classes

Comment: what error are you getting? in this particular case, you will have to do a lot of stuff manually while the `generic` class based view handles the boilerplate stuff for you.

Comment: i have updated the `urlpattern` to use the `as_view` method. Check if your issue gets resolved.